# CPagination with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Using the Yii framework:

I'm trying to implement CPagination with Ajax. The reason why is the page (that has the pagination) is being loaded as a Ajax return function(data) into a div status like $("div#status).html(data). I'm using renderPartial to load the view that has the pagination. The pagination works, but its not in ajax. I want it to do it in ajax and return the results into $(div#status)

Thanks,
mnouh

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new Pager widget, by extending CLinkPager. After extending I override one of its methods, and switched CHtml::link to CHtml:: ajaxLink.

```
    <?php

class MoPager extends CLinkPager {


protected function createPageButton($label, $page, $class, $hidden, $selected) {
    //parent::createPageButton($label, $page, $class, $hidden, $selected);

    if($hidden || $selected)
                    $class.=' '.($hidden ? self::CSS_HIDDEN_PAGE : self::CSS_SELECTED_PAGE);
    return '<li class="'.$class.'">'.CHtml::ajaxLink($label,$this->createPageUrl($page), array('success'=>'js:function(data) {
                                                jQuery("div#info").html(data);}'), array('live'=> false)).'</li>';
}



}


?>
```